# How to Automate the Security Pop Up Box in Selenium(java)?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, mozilla, autoit

I am very new to Software Automation process and trying to learn some stuff using selenium. I am automating a web application which needs security code to be entered in a pop up box to confirm the Identity after performing Single Sign-On login. I could not find any apt solutions online. I have heard of AutoIT software. Is it possible to automate it using AutoIT? If 'No' then any other solutions? Apologies if this is a stupid question. Kindly enlighten me. Please find the below screenshots:

[Security Pop Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAA9h.jpg)

[Security Pop Up 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkQce.jpg)

In the first Pop Up I need to click on "Don't have Security Code?" which navigates to another pop up asking the way to send the security code.

It would be a great help for me if anyone could give me suggestions. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you using Selenium IDE or Webdriver?

Comment: You can use sikuli with selenium for visual automation

Comment: Using selenium Web driver

Comment: @AGdev- Sikuli is for Image based automation right? I need to handle a Semantic VIP security code pop up box on a login page. Does it help?